# Call a dataframe from a list with the names of dataframes

Tags: python, list

I have a list with all the names of my dataframes (e.g list =['df1','df2','df3','df4'] I would like to extract specifically df4, by using something like list[3], meaning instead of getting the 'df4' to get the df4 dataframe itself. help?

Comment: create a dictionary `d=dict(zip(['df1','df2','df3','df4'],[df1,df2,df3,df4]))` , then call each key `d['df1']` to see `df1`

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have this in pseduocode:

```
df1 = DataFrame()
df2 = DataFrame()
df3 = DataFrame()
df4 = DataFrame()

your_list = ["df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"]
```

And your goal is to get `df4` from `your_list['df4']`

You could, instead, put all the dataframes in the list in the first place, rather than strings.

```
your_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

Or even better, a dictionary with names:

```
list_but_really_a_dict = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2, "df3": df3, "df4": df4}
```

And then you can do `list_but_really_a_dict['df1']` and get `df1`

Comment: Please don't call a list list in python

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 true, changed. Was just following OP's example. Thanks for the note!